# Flow for Knowledge publication, SCHEDULE_ARTICLE_FOR_PUBLICATION, Invalid date format

Tags: lightning-knowledge

I made a flow to schedule publish and archive knowledge , but for SCHEDULE_ARTICLE_FOR_PUBLICATION method, i have to input the 'Schedule Publish Date', i use the date that the user input in the screen, as in the screenshot, i also tried with a datetime input, do not work neither. Could you please help me?

Error Occurred: Invalid date format.

Thank you for your help
[image]

Comment: PublicationScheduledDate needs to be of type text and the value needs to be in the format '2023-01-26T00:00:00.000+0000'

Comment: As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_knowledge.htm) Input of `pubAction` is Type `String`

Answer (score 0):

`PublicationScheduledDate` needs to be of type text and the value needs to be in the format '2023-01-26T00:00:00.000+0000'

As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_knowledge.htm) Input of pubAction should be String

> **pubAction**
>
> **Type**: string
>
> **Description** Required. Publish action.Valid actions are:
>
> PUBLISH_ARTICLE (which replaces the latest version)
>
> PUBLISH_ARTICLE_NEW_VERSION (which creates a new version)
>
> SCHEDULE_ARTICLE_FOR_PUBLICATION
>
> PUBLISH_TRANSLATION

You could create a formula field with Text datatype which converts the inputted date something like

```
TEXT(DATEVALUE({!pubDate})) +'T'+IF( OR( VALUE( MID( TEXT( {!pubDate}- (8/24) ), 12, 2 ) ) = 0, VALUE( MID( TEXT( {!pubDate}- (8/24)), 12, 2 ) ) = 12 ), "12", TEXT( VALUE( MID( TEXT( {!pubDate}- (8/24) ), 12, 2 ) ) - IF( VALUE( MID( TEXT( {!pubDate}- (8/24)), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, 0, 12 ) ) ) & ":" & MID( TEXT( {!pubDate}- (8/24)), 15, 2 ) & ":" & MID( TEXT( {!pubDate}- (8/24)), 18, 2 ) +".000"+"+"+"0000"
```